# How to connect MacOS X Snow Leopard to a Windows Server 2008 VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, mac-osx

My Windows PC can connect without problems to a Windows Server 2008 VPN at my office. Everything works.

I set up the same VPN in my Mac with Snow Leopard. It connects, but I can't access any remote computer inside office's VPN.

I have played with some VPN settings, but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Oh yes, please let's restart it.
I tried to connect a MacBook Air to a MS VPN without success.
The connection should be authenticated with certificates. I had success with Cisco VPN, but that is about to be replaced with the MS VPN. So, what do I need therefore? Can it be done with the MacOSX built in VPN client (preferred), or do I need a software like IPSecuritas? Which information do I need to enter?
It is a very large MS network (AD, Kerberos) what should be connected to.
I am Mac related, left-handed with MS. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

- already tried to use the IP address of the server?
- double checked routing settings on your mac?
- tried to check the "send all traffic over VNP"
- remote IP address range conflicts with the local one? (routing problems again)

Comment: * IP doesn't work.
* How can I check the routing settings on my mac? I'm very new to mac world.
* Tried, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When VPN'd in from your mac could you run the following commands from a terminal and give us the output:

```
sudo ifconfig

sudo route
```

When VPN'd in on your windows machine could you give the output of the following 2 commands and give us the output:

```
ipconfig /all

route print
```

Comparing these will show if you have similar routing when connected on each device and ensure that you are getting a correct IP on your mac like you are on your PC.  My initial suspicion is that you are not getting a correct default gateway update or route update on your mac like you are on your PC.  This was too long to coherently put as a comment.